# Failed to convert ID value to record name

Tags: php, laravel

I'm wanting to list all the records in the `Fighter` table just containing the column `id` and `name` and make the `<td>` be done a ternary if check to verify that `$disciples->id == $msf->id_fighter (id_fighter is foreign key of table fighter by id)` that instead of returning only the number of the foreign key shows the Fighter name to facilitate the query, but the error that appears for me is:

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

- `MasterController.php`

```
    $master = MasterModel::paginate(5);
    $disciples = FighterModel::get(['id','name']);
    $count_masters = DB::table('master')->distinct()->count('name');
    return view('master.master', compact(['master','count_masters','disciples']));
```

- `Column of table`

```
    @foreach ($master as $msf)
      ...
      <td> {{ $disciples->id == $msf->id_fighter ? $disciples->name : ''}}</td>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

At this point (iside the TD) $disciples is an array containing all FighterModel rows. With that in mind, id is inside of each row. So the way to access the id attribute is by using the arrray key like $disciples[0].
You may want to do a foreach loop, for example:

```
@foreach($disciples as $k=>$v)
<td>{{ $v->id == $msf->id_fighter ? $v->name : ''}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: It actually works, but I ended up putting a foreach to return the names inside the foreach of the ```master``` table that already existed and ended up generating a disorganization in the table.

Comment: I may have failed to point out that you ussually use foreach in rows and not in tds
@ foreach<tr> ...td td td td td td. . </tr> @ endforeach